# error message in simple .vimrc file

Tags: vim

When I put in my .vimrc file:

"set backspace =2;
set nocompatible;
syntax on;"

It works fine and uses these settings when I open a new vim file however I get the error message:

Error detected while processing /mount/autofs/home_stude1/a/afarah/.vimrc:
line    1:
E474: Invalid argument: backspace =2;
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: nocompatible;

probably trivial, but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following instead.

```
set backspace=2 nocompatible
syntax on
```

Vim's script syntax does not use semicolons AFAIK.

Comment: I just figured it out. Thank you.